# In Android Browser link does not always execute onClick causing focus instead

Tags: android, webkit, focus, onclick, webview

I am trying to program a very standard JS behavior for a link using an HREF
onClick handler, and I am facing a strange problem caused by what I believe to be focus/touch mode behavior on Android.

Sometimes when I click on the link, instead of executing the action, it simply becomes selected/focused, with either just a focus rectangle or even also with a filled focus rectangle (selected as opposed to just focused?).

The pseudo-code right now is

```
<a href="#" onClick="toggleDivBelowToShowHide(); return false;">go</a>
```

I have tried doing something like:

```
<a href="#" onTouchStart="toggleDivBelowToShowHide(); return false;">go</a>
```

But I still get the same pesky problem some of the time.

Comment: To clarify some latest findings: I can definitely tell it only does NOT work when the item has the focus rectangle and I click on it in some particular way. In this case, the item then gets "selected" (briefly fully turns blue) and only does this instead of doing the action. Is there something like "onSelect"?

Comment: As in, automatically executes your function when its focused?

Comment: Well, it seems to be already focused at this point... I want the user to just be able to click on the item and expand it. It looks like +/- expanding item.

Comment: It the whole link focussed/selected? Or maybe just part of the link text? (Might be a bit hard to test with just "go".) Like: if I click slightly to the right of your name above, and then drag leftwards, I select the text of your name, letter-by-letter.

Comment: I also have this problem - sometimes android just doesn't want to follow links.  In my app, however, this can be fixed if I remove all of the preventDefault() handlers...   Which unfortunately breaks the app a little bit, but at least the links work?

Comment: I can kind of circumvent this - overloading touchstart and touchend to fire simulated mousedown / mouseup events causes the links to receive those, and if a little logic were added to touchend to also fire a click event, it should work.

Answer (score 2):

Try enabling Javascript on the webview.

In the activity that holds the webview, try this...

```
WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

I was having he same problem, but figured out it was because I did not enabled Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Try getting rid of the `href` attribute and see if that helps. For example, this works when viewed with the `WebView` component:

```
<p><a onClick="whereami()">Update Location</a></p>
```

Comment: I am sorry, that does not work for me -- it's still possible to "select" the link. I've also tried DIVs -- those are selectable too as long as they have an onClick attribute on them.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if it's related to the `onclick` -- am I correct to assume that every now and then clicking *any* link does not follow it? To me, this seems related to the way you touch the screen (or how this is interpreted), like maybe by clicking *next* to the link and dragging a bit, rather than clicking *on* the link?

(If my assumption is correct, then this might be faulty hardware: maybe you can try on another device? Or maybe it only happens on a particular side of the link if the screen is not aligned well, and then there might be some software offset one can change?)

Comment: Sorry, we have many phones here -- it's not a hardware issue. It's somehow by the fact that you can select elements.

Comment: @Artem, but this never occurs for normal links? (Links without any `onclick`?)

Comment: It is a lot harder to tell with normal links, because normal links usually leave the page, whereas this behavior requires clicking on it several times to get it to be selected. I will keep testing this.

Answer (score 0):

Try inserting this "driver" into your page code, and let us know if it works . . . It seems to be working on my site which had the same problem:

```
//Mouse & Touch -> Consistent Click / Mouse Commands -> Useful driver
(function() {
  var isTouch = false;
  var simulated_flag = 'handler_simulated';
  var touch_click_array = {};
  const clickMoveThreshold = 20; //Pixels

  function mouseHandler(event) {
    if (isTouch) {
      if (!event.hasOwnProperty(simulated_flag)) {
        //Unreliable mouse commands - In my opinion
        var fixed = new jQuery.Event(event);
        fixed.preventDefault();
        fixed.stopPropagation();
      }
    }
    else {
      //Mouse commands are consistent
      //TODO: generate corresponding touches
    }
  }

  function mouseFromTouch(type, touch) {
    var event = document.createEvent("MouseEvent");
    event.initMouseEvent(type, true, true, window, 1, touch.screenX, touch.screenY, touch.clientX, touch.clientY
      , false, false, false, false, 0, null);
    event[simulated_flag] = true;

    touch.target.dispatchEvent(event);
  };

  function touchHandler(event) {
    var touches = event.changedTouches
      ,first = touches[0]
      ,type = ""
      ;

    if (!event.hasOwnProperty(simulated_flag)) {
      isTouch = true;

      //Simulate mouse commands
      switch (event.type) {
        case "touchstart":
          for (var i = 0; i < touches.length; i++) {
            var touch = touches[i];
            touch_click_array[touch.identifier] = { x: touch.screenX, y: touch.screenY };
          }
          mouseFromTouch("mousedown", first);
          break;

        case "touchmove":
          for (var i = 0; i < touches.length; i++) {
            var touch = touches[i];
            var id = touch.identifier;
            var data = touch_click_array[id];
            if (data !== undefined) {
              if (Math.abs(data.x - touch.screenX) + Math.abs(data.y - touch.screenY) > clickMoveThreshold) {
                delete touch_click_array[id];
              }
            }
          }
          mouseFromTouch("mousemove", first);
          break;

        case "touchcancel":
          //Not sure what should happen here . . .
          break;

        case "touchend":
          mouseFromTouch("mouseup", first);
          for (var i = 0; i < touches.length; i++) {
            var touch = touches[i];
            if (touch_click_array.hasOwnProperty(touch.identifier)) {
              mouseFromTouch("click", touch);
              delete touch_click_array[touch.identifier];
            }
          }
          break;
      }
    }
  }

  document.addEventListener("mousedown", mouseHandler, true);
  document.addEventListener("mousemove", mouseHandler, true);
  document.addEventListener("mouseup", mouseHandler, true);
  document.addEventListener("click", mouseHandler, true);

  document.addEventListener("touchstart", touchHandler, true);
  document.addEventListener("touchmove", touchHandler, true);
  document.addEventListener("touchcancel", touchHandler, true);
  document.addEventListener("touchend", touchHandler, true);

})();
```

Now it isn't a 100% complete script - multi-touch would probably be a little wonky, and if you built an interface depending on touch commands, it doesn't generate those in this version.  But, it fixed my link-clicking problem.

Erm - ps - it's using jQuery.  If you need a non-jQuery version, you can probably just remove the `new jQuery.Event` from the `mouseHandler()` function (in other words, use the original event: `var fixed = event;`), and I believe most browsers would be ok.  I am not exactly a js compatibility expert though.

PPS - Tested with Android 1.6

PPPS - Had to modify script to allow a threshold - actual devices were having some problems with a move event being fired during the press.  Probably not ideal; if anyone wants to chime in on a better way for doing that, I'd be interested in hearing...

Comment: Very interesting solution... We had a bit more luck with all of this clicking by simply making a larger colored rectangle around the text... I would love to try your solution though when we get back to this.

Comment: Yeah, it works pretty well - I had to write the touch -> mouse events anyway in my app to get real-time information on dragging operations; I *should* have started with a mouse -> touch driver, and just written my app using the touch code, and will probably go that direction, but unfortunately I myself do not actually own a smartphone, so I started with mouse code.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I came across exactly the same problem. I was using the onclick on a button. Sometimes it did not execute the javascript at all. The thing that worked for me was that **enable the javascript before loading a url** in the webview

```
    // Enable javascript
    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    // To bind javascript code to android
    mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(this), "Android");

    mWebView.loadUrl(url);
```