# Click events not registered

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, webkit

This is the main screen of the Android app. Everything's rendered inside a WebView.
[image]

When I hit the button in the bottom left corner, this overlay opens, with its contents dynamically added to it.
[image]

When I hit one of the icons, it should get added to the bar on the left. And so it does.
[image]

When I hit another icon, though, nothing happens at all. The function it should call does not run (I checked by putting an `alert ()` at the beginning of it).

When I close the overlay (button in the top left corner), and open it again (bottom left), I can add another icon. But yet again, the next event will not trigger until the overlay is closed and opened once more.

I don't know how easy this is going to be to fix, as I'm not sure whether everyone experiences this issue. I (on my Samsung GT-P6200 running Android 4.0.4) do. Someone else complained to me about it as well. In the Android emulator included in the SDK, however, no such thing seems to occur with Android 4.1 and 4.1. It seems to be a 4.0 problem.

An icon in the overlay looks like this; `<div class="appLauncher" onClick="launchApp (' + i + ')"><img src="data:image/png;base64,' + base64 + '" alt="[~]" /><br /><span>' + label + '</span></div>`

I use jQuery to mess around with the DOM, if it makes any difference.

```
function launchApp (i)
{
    // Putting an alert () here indicates that the function doesn't get called, because no alert box appears on the screen //
    try
    {
        if (! launcherEdit)
        {
            android.launchAppFromList (i);
        }
        else
        {
            addAppToLauncherFromList (i); // This is what should happen //
        }
    }
    catch (ex)
    {
        handleException (ex);
    }
}
```

The app itself can be found here; https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=be.robinj.ubuntu 
It's source code can be found here; http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~robinj/be.robinj.ubuntu/trunk/files 
And this is the Javascript file; http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~robinj/be.robinj.ubuntu/trunk/view/head:/assets/script.js

---

And please, just please, don't close this as an *"exact duplicate"* without properly understanding what the actual issue is, like has happened plenty of times before.

---

This bloody mess only seems present on Android 4.0.4 and lower (or somewhere around that version number). It's only clicks on the appLaunchers that are complete ignored.

---

I'm starting to see some kind of connection here... It always starts failing after the jQuery animation adding the item to the left bar has played. This is starting to look suspiciously like a redrawing issue...

---

Not sure whether this is related, but saw it popping up in my console...

```
02-12 14:30:22.650: E/dalvikvm(3936): JNI ERROR (app bug): attempt to use stale global reference 0xe
02-12 14:30:22.650: E/dalvikvm(3936): VM aborting
02-12 14:30:22.650: A/libc(3936): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadd00d (code=1)
```

Comment: Any JavaScript errors on the second (not working) click?

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Nope, absolutely nothing. I do get the orange glow around the item I clicked, though. That tells me I did actually "hit" it.

Comment: Could you programmatically close and open the overlay after the first icon has been added?

Comment: Now it doesn't even f'ing trigger the first click. I feel like I'm constantly debugging Android bullshit here in stead of developing something myself.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186317/in-android-browser-link-does-not-always-execute-onclick-causing-focus-instead was no help?

Comment: @nneonneo Yes, I have Javascript enabled..........

Comment: I must confess that I didn't look very deep into it, but when going through the for-loop you always re-check the size of appLlist:
for (var i = 0; i < appList.size (); i++)
Could there be something wrong with the setting of i. What about saving the size in a local var and check against this var?
for (var i = 0; i < appListSize; i++)

Comment: @muetzenflo That might indeed make the app a bit less responsive, but apart from that I don't see how it could make a difference. In any case, I'll just store it in a variable beforehand.

Comment: I would make sure that the function actually runs properly the first time, just in case (I mean all of the javascript to the last line in addAppToLauncherFromList). It may look like it does, but there might be something that the 4.0 OS doesn't like and maybe it breaks the layer and the javascript completely. You could put an alert at the end of addAppToLauncherFromList and see if it shows up. If it does then the problem must be somewhere before then. I'd also try to test the divs with only alert in onclick and nothing else and see if all divs work. Build up from there and see when it breaks.

Comment: @Martina I'll try that. But I assume they all run 'til the end, as the exception handling doesn't get triggered.

Comment: @RobinJ It's less about being responsive (although that could make a difference with large arrays), but about the danger that the size of the array changes during the for-loop. Imagine that you delete the first 3 elements of a 10 element array within the loop. Then the for-loop would stop after the 7th element and ignore the 8,9 and 10th element.

Comment: @muetzenflo True, but I never remove items from the list anyway. In stead, I replace them with null.

Comment: When you finish the first call do you remove click bindings from any elements or it might be the click is not at all binded. Do you have any other items you can click apart from the array ones. It seems to me like the click event was binded to only one item and not each of the list item.

Comment: @FarrukhSubhani There's no "binding" involved in the appLaunchers. It's all `onClick` attributes.

Answer (score 7):

If you are using jQuery than better use  "**bind**" event to bind your click event.

For example:

```
    <div class="appLauncher" data-id= ' + i + '">
<img src="data:image/png;base64,' + base64 + '" alt="[~]" /><br /><span>' + label + '</span></div>
```

and than in javascript file you use:

```
$(".appLauncher").bind("click",function(){
   var i=$(this)attr("data-id");
   launchApp(i);
});
```

Try and let me know does it help you or not :)

Comment: This might work. Use delegated events though, like so: `$('WRAPPER SELECTOR').on('click', '.appLauncher', function() { ... });`. This method has several advantages, see http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events.

Comment: Wouldn't this bind the event before the appLaunchers are created, and thus not have them working? Because they are dynamically added to the DOM when a button is pressed.

Comment: Use .on to bind click events when your webview dom can have dynamic elements.

Comment: This made no difference. It still only gets the first event.

Comment: can you debug if an element has onclik attached to it or not. Does all of your elements have on click event. how can we confirm this?

Comment: @FarrukhSubhani I just removed all the `onClick`'s an used `on ()`. The first one always works, and then (when `launcherEdit` is `true`) all the other events in that div stop working.

Comment: When you say `div` you mean each icon is a `div`. Can you inspect it using edge inspect maybe to see what events are attached to it. When you fire the first event chain another event at its complete or after to attach another on click to all icons and see if that works.

Comment: I chained some events. They fired just fine :/

Answer (score 2):

Not much of a javascript person, but I do know that Android makes a clear distinction between "one off" triggers and re-usable triggers (PendingIntents). Is it possible that you are somehow instantiating one off behavious of .appLaunch?

Comment: Er... I never heard about stuff like this. How do I check?

Comment: Could you add the code which android.launchAppFromList and addAppToLauncherFromList trigger into the question?. Incidentally, should addAppToLauncherFromList really be android.addAppToLauncherFromList? (again, just a thought from a non js person)

Comment: All the code can be found at http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~robinj/be.robinj.ubuntu/trunk/files

Comment: OK, I think I've found the code, and I'm clearer on what's meant to be going on. Have you checked what the html looks like after the execution of addAppToLauncherFromList? If that action semi-breaks the html, it might explain the problem. It doesn't look like the issue I was first thinking of.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you are hit by [issue 19827](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=19827)

In this case, try adding a call to [`preventDefault`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) (not tested)

```
$(".appLauncher").bind("click", function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var i = $(this)attr("data-id");
   launchApp(i);
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the easy solution never seems to be the working solution :P

Answer (score 1):

I looked at http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~robinj/be.robinj.ubuntu/trunk/view/head:/assets/script.js

You have set "var scrollable = Array ()" in your script file. Shouldn't it be new Array() or just plain []

Just try if this is related to your JNI ERROR (app bug): attempt to use stale global reference 0xe

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, but it didn't solve the problem.